# Powerpoint vba update slide master

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a modest but growing collection (~20) of PowerPoint presentations that are all based on the same master slide. What I would like to do is to ensure that if I create a new layout or modify an existing layout on any of those files that I can update all of the other presentations to reflect this programatically. Here is my attempt. I have shown the error that it generates above the line.

```
Sub UpdateTemplates()

Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim ppPres As Presentation

RecursiveDir colFiles, "C:\Users\Debra\Dropbox\School\Mathematics\Notes\Data", "*.pptm", True

For Each vFile In colFiles
    Debug.Print "Updating templates in " & vFile
    Set ppPres = Presentations.Open(vFile)
    ppPres.ApplyTemplate ("C:\Users\Debra\Dropbox\School\Mathematics\Notes\Topic Blank.potm")

Next vFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

*First*, it seems you cannot set the `SlideMaster` property directly. However, you could try a different approach.

If you want to set the template to an open presentation or a reference to a `Presentation` object:

```
ppPres.ApplyTemplate(ActivePresentation.FullName)
```

If you want to set the template to a file on disk:

```
ppPres.ApplyTemplate("C:\PATH-TO-FILE.potx")
```

*Second*, I don't quite understand the logic in your loops. First you get a list of files to loop, then you loop all open presentations and open the file `vFile` once for every time you don't get a match? That would open each `vFile` several times if you have many unrelated presentations open.

My suggestion:

1. Close all open presentations
2. Loop `colFiles`
3. Set the template with the `ApplyTemplate("C:\PATH-TO-FILE.potx")` command (using `ActivePresentation` can sometimes lead to unexpected results :-) )

Comment: Great catch on the loop logic!

Comment: I'll see how I go with the template. I'm not using a template at the moment. Perhaps I should be. I'll let you know,

Comment: Unfortunately although no error messages are generated the slide masters are not updated.

Comment: @debragail Same problem using both methods (`ActivePresentation` and template)?

Comment: I've found that the ApplyTemplate method doesn't work in all cases, it seems that if the presentation is complex then the process just silently fails. [This](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2015/04/15/powerpoint-apply-a-template/) site indicates that PowerPoint templates are more complex than those used for Word for e.g. and that you can use the 'reuse slide' feature to manually change the templates on your decks.